# Is the canonical form of LP programs unambiguous?

Tags: linear-programming

Is the canonical form of LP programs unambiguous?

Because oddly I've seen some notes describe the canonical form as replacing $\leq$ constraints with $=$. While some other notes said that canonical forms "only have $\leq$ constraints".

So what's the canonical form of LP programs?

Comment: I'm not sure that the terminology is completely standard, but I thought that a canonical form LP has the form: minimize $c^T x$ subject to $Ax=b, x \geq 0$.

Comment: @littleO Perhaps one can also intepret that the $=$ requirement is just a stricter version of "only have $\leq$ constraints". Perhaps the difference it makes is not that big in practical problems.